# Show review queue counts according to current filters of the user

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

At the moment review queues show (fuzzied?) total number of items in the queue. Instead, **the number of review items *filtered by users current filter* should be shown**.

This mostly affects Close Votes, where I now see 7,5K items to review. Then I can click on it, and see that there's at least one in my filter tags. But I have no idea how many I'd have to review to get to the blissful empty queue, and that seems to negatively affect my motivation to review Close Votes queue.

At least I'd be much more motivated to check the number of items there are to review for *me* (by my current filter), and then make *my number* 0, if I could actually see that 0. If I'm not the only one who uses filters and feels demotivated by meaningless numbers, then it might be worth it to do this small tweak. The totals could *also* be shown of course, but preferably less prominently.

Comment: The number isn't personalizable; it already is 'fuzzy' because it would kill site performance stone dead if it showed *your* possible review count..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, I was a bit afraid of performance issues, but didn't want to muddle the question with that. Still, I think that's only a technical reason to not implement the feature, even if it'd be a nice thing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters About duplicate, you yourself comment there *"It has nothing to do with tag filters."*, while this question is *all about user's filters*...

Comment: Right, but the reason this feature request cannot be implemented is answered there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Are you familiar enough with SE databases and code to conclusively say, it'd be expensive to implement? It might need something like adding a table for queue lengths per tag, or whatever, and it wouldn't have to be 100% accurate 100% of the time either. The amount of actual data to keep is very small (`number_of_queues*number_of_tags` integers, or less if this was done only for Close Votes where it'd be useful).

Comment: I am experienced enough with web development and database development to take the SE team's word for it when they say that personalising the number is way too costly. Note that I quote the SE team in my answer.

Comment: Note that it already doesn't show the same number to everyone. For example, if you flag something as "very low quality" and it enters the review queue, your number and someone else's number of reviews available will be different.

Comment: Although not real-time you can create a SEDE query, for example [Hours a tag has a close vote](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/164748/hours-a-tag-has-a-close-vote) to give you some indication for stale tags as well as [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/195048/close-votes-per-tag) for absolute counts. Do note that this query doesn't take the expiration of votes into consideration (yet)...

Comment: @rene Thanks for the queries! My SQL is rather rusty, so I couldn't have written those myself.

Comment: Turns out the current SEDE dump is 7 hours old so at the moment you're looking at relatively fresh data (normally SEDE is updated once a week on monday)

Comment: @MartijnPieters To continue about this being duplicate. This is different from having a personal count, this is count according to filter tags. Everybody with same filter tags would get same numbers.

Comment: @hyde, but with the number of possible filters available - e.g. every tag * every close reason, the cost probably isn't all that different from if it was an individual's count

Comment: @OGHaza Note that there already must be indexes etc needed for efficiently getting posts which match any of a set of 3 tags, because that is done every time a user is given next item to review. I'm not an SQL expert, so I can't say if "get next matching item" and "get count of matching items" are always radically different operations, or if they can be easily made approximately as expensive peformance-wise. But it'd seem strange to me, if SQL DB can't be easily set up to also be able to give count, not just next match...

Comment: @Darshan can you please cast a final reopen vote? This is not a dupe as this is feature request while the other is bug report.

Comment: They are substantially different operations @hyde. If you get the next item the DB can stop as soon as it's found one in the possible range. To count you have to find everything. It's certainly not impossible, but if this is being done directly on the DB then it would be significantly more expensive.

Comment: @Ben Someone with more DB knowledge than me can perhaps interject, but wouldn't the worst case be, find just first and last to get count, and certainly not "everything"? Assuming right indexes exist, but certainly those are there already there for current filter implementation...

Comment: Nope, that assumes that there is an intrinsic order, which there isn't or that there are no gaps in the sequence, which there will be. Additionally, completed reviews aren't removed from the database, they're stored. Which means you need to find based on some conditions so you're doing an index range scan to find the single item. If you then want to find the amount you need to complete the range scan rather than using a stop-key. You obviously don't need to get "everything", but everything that matches the conditions.

Comment: I find such a feature is good! I look at queues and see there are some, go into - nothing matches to my filter :(.  It would be good to see something like this  132(7), where 7 is the number of matched reviews.