# I only want to see items related to my favorite tags in the review queues

Tags: support, tags, review-queues

I am now able to see review queues, but it's showing me triage and first posts for tags that I have no expertise or knowledge in.

Is there a way to filter the review queue to only those tags that are my favourite tags? i.e. I only want to see the review queue for items related to the one language that I use.

I get that the idea is not to review the domain-knowledge but rather to review the quality of the questions, but unless it's related to my favorite tags I'm not going to have the motivation to review them!

This is related to [Show review queue counts according to current filters of the user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255323/show-review-queue-counts-according-to-current-filters-of-the-user), but it was more concerned with Close Vote counts. Do the same arguments apply here?

Edit: I can only see this when I go to the "review" area - I don't see the filter option

[image]

Comment: The filters are visible when inside a review queue. Go in to a queue and see if it appears at the top.

Comment: You're right, when I click on the "first posts" or "late answers" queue I can see the filter option. Thanks! Strangely the "Triage" queue doesn't have the filter option.

Comment: I feel like it would make more sense to have the filter option in the front page of the review area, then have the filters apply across all queues

Comment: @terrylynch they could make them more obvious, but many users have different filters for each queue.  For example, I generally do not filter the suggest edit or low quality reviews and usually don't filter close vote queue by tag because there are more cases in which domain knowledge is not needed (and when it is needed, the skip button is handy).  But when using many of the other queues, I may filter based on tag.  Plus some of the queues (close and reopen especially) have different filters than the others.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can apply filters within each review queue by clicking the "not so obvious" link at the top. Just access any of the queues and you should see the filter option shown below:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: I'm not seeing that?

Comment: Yeah maybe my reputation still isn't high enough to see the filer? See screenshot in original post

Comment: For future reference, the filter option is found within each queue rather than in the main page of the review area.

Comment: I can't see that "filter" link at least at Review|Triage page (maybe other pages do have it) at least at http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage. I would appreciate it if you could help. Thanks!

Comment: @mvidelgauz: I can't see the filter. How did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Christoph I didn't. This filter seems not to be available everywhere

Comment: @mvidelgauz Should we try to re-open the question?

Comment: @Christoph If there is a chance to get an answer, a workaround or may be to draw SO developers attention...

Comment: All the queues seem to have the filter apart from Triage, which might be by design due to the nature of the questions that appear in that queue. Triage is all about the quality of the question, and with the low volume of question in that queue, perhaps the filter is deemed as not necessary.

Comment: @Tanner I had to skip all questions as I can only judge R/git/github and matlab. But maybe my knowledge is too narrow. In that case I am fine but I won't be able to support. I think the filter was really helpful and make support much more efficient.