# If you choose flag in the new triage queue and then scroll, the dialogue hides behind the Actions section

Tags: bug, status-completed, triage, user-interface

Here you can see I've scrolled down a little and suddenly the flag dialogue hides itself behind the Action button section.

[image: Sceenshot of the problem]

If you don't scroll then everything's OK...

[image: OK screenshot]

Comment: This happens in the close vote queue, too; however, by default the dialog is placed at a lower position there, so the problem only occurs with longer posts.

Comment: Now also reported here: [Announcing tweaks to the Triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402538/4642212).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed with the new review queue UX.

The problem did manifest itself in a different way there, only being obstructed in narrow viewports when the responsive action UI appeared.  The fix was to bring this in line with our new z-index standard, promoting it to `.z-modal` (9000) in line with other modals we display.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this will no longer be an issue with the [new UI for review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues), but I'm adding this to our list of issues to check out to make sure. Thanks for the report!

We'll post an update here once that's done.