# Choosing "Looks OK" in LQP Queue results in an "Approve" review

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, low-quality-posts

When choosing "Looks OK" in the Low Quality Posts queue, the review would normally be recorded as "Looks OK". But following the changes to the Triage queue they are now being recorded as "Approve", even though the button still says "Looks OK".

Is this a bug caused by [changes to triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402478), or is this by design?

Comment: I'm sure it's just them not having updated the button text yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up; I've fixed this issue and actually changed "Approve" back to "Looks OK" across the board.