# New Triage option "Needs author edit" shows up as "24" in Network Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, triage, network-profile

The [new "Needs author edit" option in Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402478/announcing-tweaks-to-the-triage-queue) is not displayed correctly in the [Stack Exchange Network Profile "Activity" section](https://stackexchange.com/users/11644720/janw?tab=activity).

Instead of the chosen review action, it merely displays "24":

[image: Activity section shows "24" instead of "Needs author edit"]

In general it seems like the strings haven't been updated there yet, as the list also still shows "Unsalvageable" instead of "Flag".

In order to reproduce,

- pick a random user who completed a few Triage reviews today,
- navigate to their profile,
- click "Network Profile" in the top right corner,
- click "Activity" in their network profile.

Comment: seems like we should expect to see a reason id `24` in `ReviewTaskResultTypes` table after the weekly update :) What you saw suggests a possible bug where the id leaked into the UI instead of the actual text - so, good catch!

Comment: I made this a little better by deploying se.com to production so it picks up the new options, but looks like we still need to do some additional work to show the renamed Unsalvageable result and maybe add spaces to `NeedsAuthorEdit`.

Comment: @AdamLear  Probably to the `SuggestedEditOverrideToApproved` and `SuggestedEditOverrideToRejected` while we are at it? :) P.s. Fellow SEDE users, as expected, reason #24 and renamed #22 and #23 are available in the `ReviewTaskResultTypes` table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the report! We've resolved this issue, so triage strings should be showing up properly now in your network profile.